# Concrete implementation for javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter.stringToValue(String)

Tags: java, swing, exception

I am providing a concrete implementation for:

- [javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter.stringToValue(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter.html#stringToValue-java.lang.String-)

In my case I need to handle [`java.time.LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html), so I initially wrote:

```
@Override
public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
    return LocalTime.parse(text);
}
```

Turns out, I actually needed to convert the exception myself:

```
@Override
public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
    try {
        return LocalTime.parse(text);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        // API expect a ParseException to report an error in conversion
        // need to cast DateTimeParseException into ParseException 
        throw new ParseException(e.getParsedString(), e.getErrorIndex());
    }
}
```

I am wondering if there is anything simpler to convert a `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException` into a `java.text.ParseException`, or am I missing something obvious to cast one exception to the other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question you might be able to use the `Throwable#initCause(Throwable)` method.

> [Throwable#initCause(Throwable) (Java Platform SE 8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#initCause-java.lang.Throwable-)
>
> Initializes the cause of this throwable to the specified value. (The cause is the throwable that caused this throwable to get thrown.)
>   This method can be called at most once. It is generally called from within the constructor, or immediately after creating the throwable. If this throwable was created with Throwable(Throwable) or Throwable(String,Throwable), this method cannot be called even once.

```
@Override
public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
  try {
    return ...;
  } catch (DateTimeParseException ex) {
    throw (ParseException) new ParseException(
      ex.getMessage(), ex.getErrorIndex()).initCause(ex);
  }
```